# Question about the mutation of a cluster seed associated to any word of the braid semigroup

Tags: braid-groups, cluster-algebras, associative-algebras

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group with the set of positive simple roots $\prod$. Let $\prod^{-}$ be the set of negative simple roots and let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the semigroup freely generated by $\prod$ and $\prod^{-}$. Then the **braid semigroup** is the quotient of the semigroup $\mathfrak{M}$ by some **braid relations** which related to the Cartan matrix $C$.

In the paper 'Cluster $\mathcal{X}$ -varieties, amalgamation and Poisson-Lie groups'
 https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0508408.pdf written by V. V. Fock and A. B. Goncharov. On page 16, in order to explain the fact a mutation of a cluster seed $J(D)$ is not always a cluster seed corresponding to another word of the semigroup.I am at a loss for the following example.

**Example** Let $\prod=\{\gamma,\Delta,\eta\}$ be the root system of type $A_3$ with $C_{\eta\gamma}=0$. Then $\mu_{\binom{\gamma}{1}}J(\gamma \Delta \eta\gamma\Delta\gamma)=J(\Delta\gamma\Delta\eta\Delta\gamma)$, but $\mu_{\binom{\Delta}{1}}J(\gamma \Delta \eta\gamma\Delta\gamma)$ is a seed which does not correspond to any word.

Since $C_{\eta\gamma}=0$, then $\eta\gamma=\gamma\eta$ by the braid relation, which implies that $\gamma \Delta \eta\gamma\Delta\gamma=\gamma \Delta \gamma\eta\Delta\gamma$. Thus $\mu_{\binom{\gamma}{1}}J(\gamma \Delta \gamma\eta\Delta\gamma)=J(\Delta\gamma\Delta\eta\Delta\gamma)$. But I don't know how to mutate $\mu_{\binom{\Delta}{1}}J(\gamma \Delta \eta\gamma\Delta\gamma)$? Who can give me some mutation rule? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't absorbed the details of the construction, but I think the point is, given a word in the simple roots, the authors define a particular seed based on that word.  You can mutate that seed in the sense of cluster algebras.  The point they are making is that the result of this mutation may not be a seed corresponding to any word.  The same kind of thing happens in the work of Buan-Iyama-Reiten-Scott, which may be easier (or else I have just gotten used to it).